# $f(f(x)) = x \Longleftrightarrow f(x) = x$ if $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing. Can it work for monotonically decreasing $f(x)$ or $f(f(f(x)))$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, problem-solving, monotone-functions

If $f(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function, then equations  $f(f(x)) = x$ and  $f(x) = x$ are equivalent, meaning I can solve a simpler equation $f(x) = x$ instead of a more complex one $f(f(x)) = x$.

Here is an example of this: instead of solving $1 + \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}} = x$ I can solve $1+\sqrt{x} = x$

The trick above is possible because $f(x) = 1+\sqrt{x}$  is a monotonically increasing function.

*Question 1:* the trick above needs strictly monotonic (strictly increasing) or weakly increasing (non-decreasing) would also work?

*Question 2:* is there any rule like that for $f(f(f(x))) = x$ or $f(f(f(f(x)))) = x$, etc  ($f$ being monotonically increasing)?

*Question 3:* can the trick above work for monotonically *decreasing* function? And how?  $f(f(x)) = x\Longleftrightarrow f(x) = -x$ ?

*Question 4:* is there any rule like that for $f(f(g(x))) = x$ or $f(g(g(x))) = x$ being $f$ or $g$ or both are monotonic?

Comment: For (3) consider $f(x)=1-x$

Answer (score 1):

**It may help**

Generally $f(f(x))=x$ means that the function $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ ($f(x)$
is self inverse if it is a a bijection). $f(x)=x$ happens to be a self inverse function.

So the double arrow in your title is not OK it works in reverse only.

Some interesting self inverse functions are $f(x)=\pm x, a/x, (1-x^k)^{1/k}, x\in [0,1], k>0, f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx-a}.$

Comment: I think OP meant $f(f(x))=x$ for some $x$, not for all $x$.